# Create File and unable users to delete it C#

Tags: c#, file-permissions, delete-file

I am creating a file like this:

```
System.IO.File.Create("file.dat").Close();
```

I want to set the file's permissions to disallow users from removing it. I tried the following, but it didn't work:

```
System.Security.AccessControl.FileSecurity fSecurity = File.GetAccessControl(dirPath + "\\" + fileName);

fSecurity.AddAccessRule(new System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule("Administrators",
    System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemRights.Delete, System.Security.AccessControl.AccessControlType.Allow));

File.SetAccessControl(dirPath + "\\" + fileName, fSecurity);
```

Comment: Which operating system? I can only assume you are referring to Windows because it is C#. In any event keeping the file open in your program will prevent it from being deleted. The user will always find a way to delete it if he wants to so you can also make the file hidden. Would that resolve your issue?

Comment: Yes, i´m using Windows. I want to prevent delection even after the application is closed. Turning it hidden could be a solution but i prefer keep it visible. I'm also consider making users able to remove it just with admin permissions.

Answer (score 1):

File permissions can be set using System.IO.File.SetAccessControl

See documentation and examples on MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.setaccesscontrol.aspx

To deny delete permissons to all users but administrators you can use this code

```
    FileSecurity fSecurity = File.GetAccessControl(fileName);

    AuthorizationRuleCollection rules = fSecurity.GetAccessRules(true, true, typeof(System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier));
    foreach (AuthorizationRule rule in rules)
    {
        System.Security.Principal.NTAccount account = 
            (System.Security.Principal.NTAccount)rule.IdentityReference.Translate(typeof(System.Security.Principal.NTAccount));
        if (account.Value != "BUILTIN\\Administrators")
        {
            fSecurity.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule(account.Value, FileSystemRights.Delete, AccessControlType.Deny));
        }
    }

    File.SetAccessControl(fileName, fSecurity);
```

Comment: In that example how can i specify that just user with admin previlegies can do stuff ?

Comment: Thanks for help, but unfortunatly it didn't work. After creating the file i'm continue able to remove it. But create it hidden solves my problem too.